# Expansion of $(a + b x^4 + c x^6 + dx^8)^{-1} $

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I am asked to expand
$$
(a + b x^4 + c x^6 + dx^8)^{-1}
$$
and take the limit $x \rightarrow 0$ of the result. Is it fair neglect the higher powers at the first place and talk about
$$
(a + b x^4 + c x^6 + dx^8)^{-1}  \approx (a + b x^4)^{-1}?
$$
Here, $a,b,c,d$ are constants.

Comment: If you can prove it with the tools you have at hand, then it's fine. It doesn't look like that is the case, but then again I kind of don't understand the question as a whole.

Comment: Yes.. on the surface  $(a+bx^4)^u$ where  $(u=-1) $ will be the only term that will evalute to $\frac {1}{a}$ (at $x=0$) and the rest of the terms will contain the product $-+(cx^6+dx)^k(a+bx^4)^u $ where $k >=1 $ and $u=n-k$ and $k$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here it's fine to neglect the higher powers since we are taking the limit as $x\rightarrow 0,$ so terms of order $O(x)$ and higher vanish.

For $a\neq 0$, we should obtain

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \space (a+bx^4+cx^6+dx^8)^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$$

We have  $$\frac{1}{(a+bx^4+cx^6+dx^8)}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{a}(bx^4+cx^6+dx^8))}$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\big(1-\frac{1}{a}(bx^4+cx^6+dx^8)+\frac{1}{a^2}(bx^4+cx^6+dx^8)^2+...)$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{a^2}x^4+...=\frac{1}{a}+O(x^4)\space \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{x\rightarrow 0}\space\frac{1}{a}$$